# This japanese font could be identified?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

I need help to identify this 2 fonts, the both font is used in super sentai series, the first one in Kyuranger and the other is used in Megaranger.

[image]

Megaranger examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have searched all over google and font sites, but it cant be found, which is why I'm asking here.

Thanks too much.

Comment: These seem to be two different fonts (the difference between "su" in the first image and "ra" in the second is obvious)

Comment: Yes. I want to know what are the two fonts, I haven't been able to find both.

Comment: Then please split the question in two. An answer might identify the first perfectly, but forget about the second or get it incorrectly&mdash;and is it to be marked correct, then? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the first image, almost all characters except square brackets, kanji 日 and colon are from [花風テクノ](https://fontworks.co.jp/font/design/kafutechno/H.html).

[image]
(sample using 花風テクノ H)

The next three use ゴーシャ. This font is currently hardly obtainable in DTP because its vendor (写研) only bundles it with their professional typesetting machines (that only TV stations and publishers can afford). However you can buy outlines of specific glyphs through some Japanese sites such as [this one](http://www.net-dtp.com/). Below is specimen of this family, for your information.

[image]
([source](http://imadakin1.seesaa.net/article/402009862.html))